# Blender Bmesh set custom normal

Tags: python, normals, bmesh

I'm trying to adjust the normals of selected vertexes on a vector. The code runs without errors but does nothing.
Blender version 4.0.2

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from mathutils import Vector

obj = bpy.context.active_object

if obj.type != 'MESH':
    raise ValueError("Активный объект не является сеткой")

bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(obj.data)
bm.verts.ensure_lookup_table()

selected_verts = [v.index for v in bm.verts if v.select]

print(selected_verts)
bm.select_mode = {'VERT'}
v = bm.verts[selected_verts[0]]
v.normal = Vector((1.0, 0.0, -1.0))  # Установка пользовательской нормали

bm.normal_update()
bmesh.update_edit_mesh(obj.data)

bm.free()
```